# Is there a way to automate the generation of different combinations of rows within groups, based on values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I just wanted to ask a little help on R in doing combinations of rows based on non consecutive values.
I have been looking online, but wanted also your expert help.

Basically I have a data frame with different columns, and 3 of these are the gene, the sequence and the rank based on a score which I already calculated.

What I need it to generate, within each group of gene, get the top 4 highest scores and generate combinations like these:
`first+ third highest`,  `second + fourth`, the third + first, (the reverse of the first and second combinations), fourth + second,  Non template + 1st, non template + 2nd,  Non template + 3rd,  Non template +4rth,  1st + non template,  2nd + NT,  3rd + NT,  4th + NT

Could you help me with this, please? How to get this in a more intelligent way and automated, maybe?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Check out `combn`

Comment: And some of your combinations seem to be redundant, e.g. non template + 1st vs. 1st + non template. These are equivalent and would get you the same results.

Comment: Thank you guys. Below I added an answer with a clearer explanation of the outcome I am looking for. Can anyone help?